# MS Word Regex to find any repeated character

Tags: regex, ms-word

For example, `ee` or `oooo` should be matched. If I type `e{2,}` into the search box, I get the right results--however, if I try to do that for *any* single character, which seems to me would be `?{2,}`, I get everything as a match. `fe` is a match, or even a character and then a space is a match. What is the right expression?

I would also like to find words that end and begin with the same character. How can the expression for this be written?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:
([A-Za-z]){2,}

Comment: Please elaborate on how this answers the question.

Comment: In MS-Word we can use ([A-Za-z]){2,} regex to find the repeated characters like lOOK, sEE, etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
/(.)\1+/g
```

is the regex we will use in php . Not sure if this will work in ms word too.